# how to display the videos in listview in youtube player?

Tags: android, android-listview, youtube-api

I'm new to android..

I'm using youtube player to display the videos. I have stored the videos in database and retrieve all videos and kept in array string. In my array first video link works fine. But i want to display my video array in list view in player were suggested videos will there in player that place i need to display my video array..

How to implement this? any help me. Thanks a lot in advance..

code..

> ```
>  vid=new ArrayList<String>(new ArrayList<String>(vid));
>     videoUrl=parsing.parse(videoUrl);
>     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
>     public void run() {
>     startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("url"+videoUrl)));
>     }
>      });
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Use `VideoView` to display video from a url

like this 
http://www.coderzheaven.com/2010/09/19/play-video-using-videoview-in-android/

and write a `custom adapter` to customize the UI of `ListView`